# How can I process a food plate aka ellipse to stack onto each other until it reaches 20 plates?

Tags: java, function, if-statement

My assignment asks me to code an ellipse similar to a plate, and stack 20 of them using if else statements and everything included from chapters 1-6 in shiffmans processing beginner's book. I need to use a button pressed function to stack 20 plates, once they reach to 20 THE "PLATES" MUST INDIVIDUALLY DISAPPEAR TO 0 ONE BY ONE WITH A MOUSE CLICK FUNCTION. This is what I have came up with so far, the plates have to start at the bottom of the screen.

```
 // Declare global (shared) variables here
 float plate1X = 50;
 float plate1Y = 200;
 int plateColor = (255);

 // Do not write any statements here (must be inside methods)

 void setup()`enter code here`
 {
   // Add statements to run once when program starts here.  For example:
   size(400,400);
   plate1X = 200;
   plate1Y = 50;
   background(255);
   plate1X = width/2;
   plate1Y = height/2;


 } // end of setup method


 void draw()
 {
   // Declare local variables here (new each time through)

   // Add statements to run each time screen is updated here
   ellipse(plate1X, plate1Y, 200,50);
   if(ellipse <= 1 || ellipse <= 0; //draw another plate);

   // Screen will be repainted automatically at the end of draw method
 } // end of draw method

 // Add other methods here
```

Comment: What is the problem you're running into? I'd be happy to answer your questions if I can, but I won't do your homework for you.

Comment: I can't figure out how to copy the plate and make it to where it will draw another plate on top of it so that it is stacked, can you mssg me? I'm new to all of this @dorr

Comment: In draw(), it looks like you're calling a function ellipse(). Is that defined for you? Where does it come from?
Then there is a variable called ellipse, in the if statement. Where is that declared?

Comment: I am drawing an ellipse to represent a plate and using ellipse in a if statement but it says it does not detect the variable 'ellipse'.

Comment: To stack another plate on top would it have to be an If statement or if else?

Answer (score 0):

"does not detect the variable 'ellipse'": That's because you didn't declare it. You need to let the compiler know what kind of variable it is before you use it. In this case, it is probably an integer, so you should have the line `int ellipse;` above the first time you use it.

You also never set `ellipse` to hold any value! You are trying to check `if(ellipse <= 1 || ellipse <= 0)`, but right now `ellipse` doesn't have any value.

Your ellipse function seems like it should draw an ellipse at the coordinates that you tell it--

`ellipse(x, y, width, height)`

so if you want to draw another ellipse, you should call `ellipse(...)` again with a new `x` and `y` value.

You will want to use if statements to make sure you only do this some of the time--specifically when you haven't gotten to 20 plates yet. Do you know what if and else statements do?

Comment: without the if statement it will draw me a ellipse centered in the screen. If statements are executed specifically if a condition is true. if else use this statement to execute some code if the condition is true and another code if the condition is false.